# Joinjs Cell vs Cellview

Tags: jointjs

In the documentation of JointJS I have often seen the terms `cell` and `cellview`. I know cell is the an `Item cell` on the graph but what is meant by `cellView`. I tried to find myself but could not figure it out !!
E.g on this link [List of triggered events](http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper:events)

following line is written:

**`cell: pointerdown` - triggered when a pointer is pressed on a cell. Takes cellView, evt, x and y as arguments.**

what is this `cellView` here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't show up in the JointJS API docs under CellView, but it's either an instance of [`joint.dia.ElementView`](http://www.jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.ElementView) or [`joint.dia.LinkView`](http://www.jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.LinkView). They both extend from `joint.dia.CellView.

Answer (score 1):

A cell is a backbone 'Model' object, and a cellView (linkView, elementView) are backbone 'View' objects. This follows the backbone MVC 'model/view/controller' paradigm.

The model represents data, where the view represents the visual presentation of that data. So in the context of joingjs cells and cellViews, the cell is the data, and the cellView is how that data is rendered in your diagram.